# how can I turn nested dictionary into flat dictionary and sum values with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

here is my dictionary:

```
d = {'dicta':{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, 'dictb':{'a':2,'b':3,'c':1}, 'dictc':{'a':2,'b':5,'c':9,'d':10}}

{'dicta': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 'dictb': {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1}, 'dictc': {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 9, 'd': 10}}
```

What I want to do is combine these nested dicts into a flat one and also sum the values to get:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 10}
```

I can already achieve this using the below code:

```
out = {}
for k,v in [[k2,d[k1][k2]] for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1]]:
    if k in out.keys():
        out[k] = out[k] + v
    else:
        out[k] = v
```

However as you can see it isn't very elegant. There must  be a better way! (Raymond Hettinger :D).

I can also do a dict comprehension which obviously only keeps one entry for each key:

```
out = {k2:d[k1][k2] for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1]}
```

output: `{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 9, 'd': 10}`

or a list comprehension that at least gives me everything I want to combine:

```
out = [{k2:d[k1][k2]} for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1]]
```

output: `[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'a': 2}, {'b': 3}, {'c': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 9}]`

Which feels like I'm getting close...

Is there a way to combine these the way I want in a really elegant way that I am just unaware of?

Something like : out = `{k2:d[k1][k2] for k1 in d for k2 in d[k1] with combined = True}` (obviously doesn't make sense but to illustrate the point)

Looking for the cleanest way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 10})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = {'dicta':{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, 'dictb':{'a':2,'b':3,'c':1}, 'dictc':{'a':2,'b':5,'c':9,'d':10}}
_d = defaultdict(int)
for a in d.values():
  for c, j in a.items():
     _d[c] += j

print(dict(_d))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 10}
```

Shorter solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
r = sorted([i for b in d.values() for i in b.items()], key=lambda x:x[0])
result = {a:sum(c for _, c in b) for a, b in groupby(r, key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 13, 'd': 10}
```

Comment: very nice.. doubt this can be improved but, I can't accept for another 5 min so we'll see :D